# Simulating Keys In Video Games

Tags: python, pyautogui

I want to code a bot that walks for me in a game called **Minecraft** To Explore All Of The Biomes. I've tried this code:

```py
import pyautogui
import time

pyautogui.keydown("w")


time.sleep(8888)

pyautogui.keyUp("w")
print("Exploration Finished")
```

But it doesn't even move how can I fix it?

Comment: Try changing `keydown` to `keyDown` and after starting your script, click on Minecraft window, so it's in focus

Comment: It didn't work.

Comment: You can try in text editor to check whether library works or not

Comment: It works with Word and Notepad

Comment: One more reason I can think of, Minecraft doesn't register keys which were pressed before window focus. Create initial delay before calling `keyDown`

Comment: Nope still doesn't...

Comment: @geobreze I found something that might be the reason pyautogui.FailSafeException but I have no idea of how to use it do you know?

Comment: Could you please share an exception? Also, you can turn off failsafe by running `pyautogui.FAILSAFE = False`

Comment: @geobreze please test your solution and post a full code to answers part to not make comments more longer.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `pyautogui` library nor with details of Minecraft input scanning. And I'm not going to install Minecraft to test my hypotheses. I've just made some subjective suggestions without knowing the exact answer to this question. I Hope, someone will test their solution and post it as answer. Good luck finding the solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have inserted a `time.sleep()` code which will wait for 8888 seconds and then finish your code, resulting nothing. So instead, I put a for loop to fix your error:

```
from pyautogui import *

for i in range(8888):
    keyDown("w")

keyUp("w")
print("Exploration Finished")
```

You can use the `time.sleep()` function to go to your game, start the game etc...

Please tell if this worked for you

Comment: Yeah… It does work but I have to implement it to pydirectinput(I’ve noticed that my server has anti-cheat). Thank you for your help!